# Set lock true for group of cells

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, closedxml

I'm using closedxml to export excel..

Now i can protect (Lock cell) cell using the following function,

```
workSheet.Cell(rowIndex,column).Style.Protection.SetLocked(true);
```

I want to set group of cells..
Is that Possible in closedxml ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Range` like so

```
workSheet.Range(startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn).Style.Protection.SetLocked(true);
```

Answer (score 13):

@Raidri, thanks for the answer that you provided here, but I want to add my own answer.

I found that when you want to lock a cell, the Worksheet must first be protected, or else the lock does nothing.

The worksheet can be protected with `workSheet.Protect()` method.  However, this will have all the cells locked by default, so you'll actually want to protect the worksheet and then *unlock* the cells you want to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

i know am late to the party but am sure someone may benefit

```
ws.Range("A1:A10").Style.Protection.SetLocked(false);ws.Range("B1:B10").Style.Protection.SetLocked(true);var protection = ws.Protect("123");protection.AllowedElements = XLSheetProtectionElements.InsertRows | XLSheetProtectionElements.SelectUnlockedCells;
```

with SelectUnlockedCells set, you will be able to edit some cells and not the locked one