# Set readonly column in closedxml column

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, closedxml

I got stuck for setting "ReadOnly" column using "ClosedXML" utility for export to Excel.
I am able to export records into Excel, however the first "ID" column I need to keep it read only, user should not type anything. If he want to add new row in the exported excel he can, except "ID" column. Please help me to solve this functionality (`ws` is my worksheet).

```
ws.Column("ID").Style.Protection.SetLocked(true);
```

Even I am setting "SetLocked" it is editable and I need non-editable field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set lock true for group of cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286191/set-lock-true-for-group-of-cells)

Comment: Please play fair and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4):

at first you need to protect the whole sheet then unlock only the cells you want to be editable as following

```
ws.Protect("yourPassword"); //hint: password parameter is optional
ws.Column("ID").Style.Protection.SetLocked(false); //set to false
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to also switch protection on for the worksheet with

```
ws.Protect()
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Sheet-Protection) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20286191/2610249) for more details.